# Can “a lot of” be used in a negative sentence or a question?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

My son's English teacher told him that "a lot of" can't be used in a negative sentence or a question. I don't think so, for I must have heard or read someone use "a lot of" in a negative sentence or in a question.

Can “a lot of” be used in a negative sentence or a question?

Comment: I use **much** and **many** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question that's best answered with examples, I think.

> Are there a lot of good players at your tennis club?
>
> That's not a lot of money.

'A lot of' is a quantifier, and its usage is quite flexible. And the above examples are valid. However, as SovereignSun alluded to in the comments, 'much' and 'many' would be more commonly used in many situations.

> Are there many good players at your tennis club?
>
> That's not much money.

Comment: "I don't have a lot of time" is in fairly common use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers) has an explaination regarding this.

We usually use *much(for uncountable moun)* and *many(for countable noun)* when we are expecting a large quantity if something isn't there. While *a lot of* or *lots of*  is used when we are expecting a large quantity of something.

Examples,

> - **Didn't you meet many people?**
>     *Here, I'm expecting that you didn't      meet many people*
> - **Didn't you meet a lot of people**
>     *Here, I'm expecting you met a lot of people and I'll be surpised if you say you didn't.*